# Image is null with Uint8List - Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, encode, uint8list

I am trying to encode an image to Uint8List but it gives me a null

```
  List<int> bytes;
  I.Image _img;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    String file = 'lib/graphics/logo.png';
    readFileAsync(file);
  }

  Future<dynamic> readFileAsync(String filePath) async {
    var imageData = await rootBundle.load('lib/graphics/logo.png');
    bytes = Uint8List.view(imageData.buffer);
    _img = I.decodeImage(bytes);
  }
```

and calling it from the widget tree

```
Container(
  child: Image.memory(_img.getBytes()),
),
```

Error

```
I/flutter (26125): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (26125): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building LayoutBuilder:
I/flutter (26125): The method 'getBytes' was called on null.
I/flutter (26125): Receiver: null
I/flutter (26125): Tried calling: getBytes()
```

Comment: Is your asset or assets path is declared in your pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: assets:
    - lib/graphics/logo.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get a null because the `load` method is a `Future` and you don't wait for it on your build method.

You have to check if `_img` is null and display another widget like a Text or CircularProgressIndicator if it is :

```
Container(
  child: _img ? Image.memory(_img.getBytes()) : Text('loading...'),
),
```

After, you need to call the `setState()` method to rebuild your widget in your `readFileAsync` method :

```
setState() {
  _img = I.decodeImage(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Thanks... It works now...I saw that the it didn't save it to the global variable... but if I used set state then it worked ....Thanks for the feedback